# Python re to retrieve pattern plus x number of characters after the pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to use python re to search for a string, and then print out that string and the next 4 characters after the string. I can not work out how to do it.

I've tried using the .{4} parameter when I print the pattern, but nothing is displayed (see my code example)

```
import re

sequence="I want to know if there are some available 123"
pattern="available"

re.search(pattern, sequence):
    print(pattern{.4})
else:
    print ("it's not there")
```

What every the next 4 characters is after the search strong 'available' I would like to print out the search string, and those 4 characters, so in the code example it would print out 'available 123'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concatenate the `.{4}` to the pattern when searching:

```
import re

sequence="I want to know if there are some available 123"
pattern="available"

res = re.search(pattern + '.{4}', sequence)
if (res):
    print(res.group(0))
else:
    print ("it's not there")
```

**Output:**

```
available 123
```

Comment: Thanks, what does the group(0) bit do?

Comment: @treetop: `group(0)` stands for the whole match. `group(1)` (not use here) is the content of the first capture group and so on for `group(2)`, `group(3)`, ...